# Where is the definition of in and out of scope?

Tags: support, scope

I hunted about, and found meta, but not a definition of what questions this community considers in and out of scope.  Where can that be found?

Answer (score 9):

Did you try the [Help Center](//webapps.stackexchange.com/help)?

It's spelled out under: [What topics can I ask about here?](//webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

You can also see previous discussions about the site scope here on Meta with the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag.